# I'm getting an error when creating a new plugin

Tags: plugins, unreal-engine5

I've been trying to create a new plugin for the purpose of using a third party library.
When I try to create a new blank plugin I get the following error:
[image]
Do you have any idea what may be wrong?

I tried creating a blank project to see, if there was something wrong with that specific project but same error.
I thought it might be a problem with permissions, so I tried running epic games as an administrator but it didn't help.

Comment: Okey, so I tried to create the plugin somwhere else, and as long as it's not in the Users subdirectory it works. Basically I can't create the plugin in the folder of my project. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey so, I found out it was a problem with my antivirus program. After turning it off, it worked as intended. Thanks anyway

Comment: mark your answer as "accepted answer" if your problem is solved